# Gunicorn, нет модуля с именем "locallibrary.wsgi"

Tags: веб-программирование, развертывание, gunicorn

[image: locallibrary]так я запускаю сайт на heroku: `gunicorn --chdir locallibrary/locallibrary locallibrary.wsgi:application  --log-file -`
и выдает ошибкy:

```
   2019-01-12T19:26:05.163068+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command gunicorn --chdir locallibrary/locallibrary locallibrary.wsgi:application  --log-file -
2019-01-12T19:26:09.315302+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-01-12T19:26:09.287486+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2019-01-12T19:26:09.116544+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-01-12 19:26:09 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-01-12T19:26:09.117420+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-01-12 19:26:09 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2019-01-12T19:26:08.847906+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-01-12 19:26:08 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
2019-01-12T19:26:08.848742+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-01-12 19:26:08 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:4525 (4)
2019-01-12T19:26:08.848894+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-01-12 19:26:08 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-01-12T19:26:08.879651+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-01-12 19:26:08 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2019-01-12T19:26:08.917617+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-01-12 19:26:08 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-01-12T19:26:08.917621+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-01-12T19:26:08.917622+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
2019-01-12T19:26:08.917624+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-01-12T19:26:08.917625+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
2019-01-12T19:26:08.917626+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-01-12T19:26:08.917628+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
2019-01-12T19:26:08.917629+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-01-12T19:26:08.917630+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-01-12T19:26:08.917632+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-01-12T19:26:08.917633+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2019-01-12T19:26:08.917634+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-01-12T19:26:08.917636+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2019-01-12T19:26:08.917637+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-01-12T19:26:08.917638+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
2019-01-12T19:26:08.917639+00:00 app[web.1]: import(module)
2019-01-12T19:26:08.917696+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'locallibrary.wsgi'
2019-01-12T19:26:08.918039+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-01-12 19:26:08 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2019-01-12T19:26:08.945562+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-01-12 19:26:08 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2019-01-12T19:26:08.952096+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-01-12 19:26:08 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-01-12T19:26:08.952100+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-01-12T19:26:08.952102+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
2019-01-12T19:26:08.952103+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-01-12T19:26:08.952105+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
2019-01-12T19:26:08.952106+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-01-12T19:26:08.952107+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
2019-01-12T19:26:08.952109+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-01-12T19:26:08.952110+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-01-12T19:26:08.952112+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-01-12T19:26:08.952113+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2019-01-12T19:26:08.952115+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-01-12T19:26:08.952116+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2019-01-12T19:26:08.952118+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-01-12T19:26:08.952119+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
2019-01-12T19:26:08.952120+00:00 app[web.1]: import(module)
2019-01-12T19:26:08.952161+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'locallibrary.wsgi'
```

**сижу много времени и многое перечитал и не помогает, что можете порекомендовать?**

Comment: Так, может, его и правда нету? Точно не просто `--chdir locallibrary` надо прописывать?

Comment: Есть он в этом проекте

Comment: https://pastebin.com/p917Ltim

Comment: О, так всё-таки импортировался? Ну теперь читайте новый текст ошибки и исправляйте её

Comment: спасибо за помощь